# How to set the thread name in OkHttp client

Tags: java, okhttp

I am using OkHttp v3.14.2 in my app. With following configuration, I could see the thread names use the URL I set. Is there a way set a custom name to the threads used by OkHttp client to invoke web requests?

My current implementation uses following code to create an instance of `OkHttp`

```java
private static OkHttpClient initializeOkHttpClient() {
    final ConnectionPool pool = new ConnectionPool(5, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    final ConnectionSpec cs = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
            .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
            .build();

    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(cs))
            .connectTimeout(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .connectionPool(pool)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build()
    ;
}
```

In the log I could see `OkHttp https://<url>/...` as the thread name.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If it didn’t, why not?

Comment: No it did not work.

Comment: What didn’t work? Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can customize the thread names for synchronous requests, but you should be able to do that for async requests. I’ll give you the general steps, not line-by-line spoon fed instructions. You need to create a custom `ThreadFactory`, which can then be passed to an `ExecutorService`, which in turn can be passed to a `Dispatcher`, that can then be used to build a OkHttp client.
Good luck.

Comment: I was using a custom `ThreadFactory`, but the thread name was still `OkHttp http://example.com/...`. [As far as I can see](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_3.14.x/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/NamedRunnable.java), in OkHttp 3.14.9, the thread name is temporarily altered by OkHttp before sending the request and reset after completion. Hence, it might not be possible.